# Nginx config is not affected on MacOS High Sierra

Tags: nginx, macos-sierra, dnsmasq

I have some issue need to clear. I have install and config nginx but not successfully. Here is my file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/error.log debug;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include             mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile            off;

    keepalive_timeout   65;

    index index.html index.php;

    include /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

file /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mage

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  mage.local;
    root       /Users/nghiepthan/Sites/html/;

    access_log /Users/nghiepthan/Sites/html/nginx.access.log;
    error_log /Users/nghiepthan/Sites/html/nginx.error.log;

    location / {
        include   /usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/php-fpm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /test.php?$query_string;
    }
}
```

I have setup dnsmasq. config of file /usr/local/etc/dsnmasq.conf

```
address=/.local/127.0.0.1
listen-address=127.0.0.1
```

Next, I had defined /etc/resolver/local nameserver 127.0.0.1

However, when I run the command curl -IL http://mage.local

I got the message: * curl: (6) Could not resolve host: mage.local*

but if I run the command

```
curl -IL http://localhost
```

I got success response like this

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Server: nginx/1.13.12 
Date: Tue, 29 May 2018 11:07:27 GMT 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 
Connection: keep-alive 
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.18
```

when I run on my browser, I type URL = localhost, It goes to my path had defined. I did not know where I was wrong. I have try to run command sudo nginx but I got this errors:

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (48: Address already in use)

nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (48: Address already in use)

nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (48: Address already in use)

nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (48: Address already in use)

nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (48: Address already in use)

nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

How can I fix these issues?

Answer (score 0):

Change `listen       80;` to `listen       8080;` You have a process already on port 80.

EDIT: Try to remove `listen-address=127.0.0.1` from dnsmasq.conf.

And restart dnsmasq with `sudo brew services restart dnsmasq`.

Always use `sudo...` when starting or stopping services that runs below port 1000.

I think its most likely the dnsresolver.

Comment: I had changed and restart nginx. but when i run command curl -IL http://mage.local:8080. I still got a message: curl: (6) Could not resolve host: mage.local

Comment: still same error after edit and restart dnsmasq with sudo :D I also add DNS on system preferences > network > DNS